# How to disable the hiding of UIAlertView in IOS

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uialertview

I am new to IOS development but cannot understand how to disable the hiding of UIAlertView in IOS. I tried a lot but cannot understand how to complete it. Can any one help me out with some code.

Comment: Please provide some code of your attempts and specify what goes wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by `"disable the hiding of UIAlertView"`?

Comment: Disable , I want to say is that when we click on the Ok button of alertview then it should not be hide. Actually I am using password textfield in Uialertview, we enter passwrod in textfield and click ok, then if password is incorrect. Then alertview should not get hidden and textfield get blank text.